# Need a precise expression of a purpose

Tags: expressions

In a piece of writing, I mention two terms, say A and B.  Traditionally they are interchangeable although the term A is favored.  The novelty of my writing is that they will eventually be distinguished.  In particular, the term B will be used in place of the term A and the term A will be used in a different sense than it currently is.  But before I reach that point, I intend to keep using the term A as usual, in order to ....  The purpose is definitely for contrast, for emphasis.  But I just can not express it precisely.

Now I want to give a remark on my intention in a footnote to inform the user beforehand.  So far I have only come up with something like:

> Until ..., these two terms are not distinguished though the term A is used till then to ....

The problem is that I do not know how to describe my purpose very precisely.  Could you help me fill in the gap at the end?  Thanks.

Comment: I advise you to establish the meanings that you ultimately want to assign to the two terms from the moment you first use them. It is hard enough for readers to accept novel (or at least unusual) definitions for terms that they already understand in a different way; it is much more difficult for them to adjust to a line of reasoning that initially accepts the standard definitions but then redefines the terms in the midst of the argument. At the very least, consider using term B consistently in the early stages of the writing and withhold term A until you're ready to unveil its special meaning.

Comment: Ah, this is actually what I do for the moment.  So it seems not worth the effort to seek for a novel way of establishing the meanings.  Do you have any support for your claim?

Comment: I don't have any independent evidence, if that's what you're asking. My assertion is based on how I react as a reader when I encounter what might be called "moving-target terminology." I'd like to think that common sense supports my position, but I could just be flattering myself.

Comment: I decide to take your suggestion.  Could you please put it into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

you could say *to avoid (lexical) ambiguity ....*

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But I am afraid that is not what is in my mind.  Because if the purpose is to avoid ambiguity, I should distinguish them from the very start.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the term **deprecate** as it is used in software development.

**[Deprecate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)**: a status applied to a computer software feature, characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically because of it being superseded.

In your example, you can declare your intent to continue to recognize the equivalence or interchangeability of A and B until that point in time when you will intentionally deprecate the term A in favor of B.

This may occur when, initially, an unfortunate term (A) was chosen to express or describe something by convention. Then, through the passage of time, a more appropriate term (B) may become more popular. Once A has been deprecated, it may be reused for some other purpose. (Of course, there might be some confusion by reusing the term A, but that's another matter.)

Some examples of Unix deprecated commands can be found at [this link](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/), along with their replacements. *Route* is a good example of a command name that might find some other more suitable reuse.